# Prove $p_{cA} = c^n \ p\left( \frac{t}{c}\right) $ is the characteristic polynomial of $\ cA $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

> Suppose $p_A (t) $ is the characteristic polynomial of matrix $\ A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n} $. Prove that, for every $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $c \neq 0$, the characteristic polynomial  $p_{cA}(t) $ of matrix $cA $ satisfies  $$p_{cA}(t) = c^n p \left(\frac{t}{c}\right). $$

I don't really have any direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: We have $\det(cA-tI)=c^n\,\det\left(A-\frac{t}{c}I\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of the characteristic of $cA$ is
\begin{align*}
p_{cA}(t) = det(tI-cA) &= c^n det(\frac{t}{c} I - A) = c^n p_{A}\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)\\
\end{align*}

which proves your result. This equality is due to [the fifth property of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) and can be checked easily